# Sin wave formula simplification and explanation?

Tags: wave-equation

I have been trying to implement this Wave equation into java:

A = amplitude of wave
L = wave length
w = spatial angular frequency
s = speed
wt = temporal angular frequency
d = direction
FI = initiatory phase

$$Y(x，y，t)=A\cdot\cos(w \cdot(x，y)+ wt\cdot t + FI)$$

I understand that it returns a Vector. But I am unsure as to what this section of the formula means:

$$w \cdot（x，y）$$

I believe that $w$ is a vector. But I'm not whether its a 3D Vector or 2D Vector, and how it is used.

Source: 
http://lnu.diva-portal.org/smash/get...412/FULLTEXT01

Comment: The link gives: ...ERROR...ERROR...ERROR...ERROR...ERROR...ERROR...ERROR...
An error occurred...

Comment: http://lnu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:205412/FULLTEXT01

Comment: It might be a bit much to expect folks to read a 66 page technical report to answer your question. You might consider giving relevant page numbers.

Comment: Didnt ask them to. I only asked them to explain that one formula. The link is merely for people who are interested in the subject.

Comment: I would guess that it is a two dimensional vector and the * means inner product?

Comment: So Vector2f w * vector2f(x,y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general equation for a *planar* wave in 3D is of the form $E : \mathbb{R}^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where

$$
E( \mathbf{r}, t ) = E_0 \cos \left( \omega t + \mathbf{k}^{T} \mathbf{r} + \varphi_0 \right),
$$

where $t$ is time, $\omega$ is temporal frequency, $\mathbf{r}$ is position, and $\mathbf{k}$ is the wave vector. The wave vector is a unit vector in the direction of propagation scaled by the wavenumber, $k = \omega / c_0 = 2\pi / \lambda$, it will often look something like

$$
\mathbf{k}
=
k
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\cos(\phi) \cos(\theta) \\
\cos(\phi) \sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\phi)
\end{array}
\right],
$$

where $\theta$ would usually be the azimuth angle and $\phi$ the elevation.

If you look at your equation, it is of the same form except that it is only using 2 spatial dimensions, $x$ and $y$. (So it's a plane wave with its propagation confined to the $x-y$ plane.) Thus, what you have written as "w*(x,y)" is $\mathbf{k}^{T} \mathbf{r}$ in the above; it is the dot product between the wave vector and the position vector.

Also, your equation does not return a vector but rather a scalar; it takes a 2D location and an instant in time and returns the scalar value of the propagating wave at that point at that particular time ($\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful. Now i am curious as to how to apply this to return a height value for each of my vertices? SO yPos would be = to K?

Comment: Is $Y(x,y,t)$ meant to be the height at location $(x,y)$ at time $t$?

Comment: Note what your equation does. It takes location as one of its inputs, with the other input being time; you have to tell it both to get a value as a plane wave oscillates in both dimensions. [This image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AC_wave_Positive_direction.gif) might help you picture it. I hope that helps, as I don't know what 'yPos' or 'K' means in this context, nor what you exactly mean by a vertex.

Comment: This thread better explains my issue: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69824/3d-water-simulation-formula-questions

Comment: @TastyLemons I don't understand why you are changing the y position of the vertices. Shouldn't the vertex be at a fixed location in the $x-y$ plane with its height determined by the wave equation? It looks like you have a mesh of points in the $x-y$ plane, so that at time $t$ vertex $i$ is at $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$, where $z_i = Y(x_i,y_i,t)$. As the value of $t$ changes, so does $z_i$, which should give you the effect of a propagating wave.